# How to create an alias of an interface from another module in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have 2 typescript files.

**commons.d.ts**

```
module "commons" {
    interface IUser {
        name:string;
    }
}
```

**main.ts**

```
import commons = module("commons");
class User implements commons.IUser {
    name:string;
}
```

Since I will use `commons.User` a lot in the `main.ts`, I want to create an alias for it. For I change the code to:

```
import commons = module("commons");

import UserAlias = commons.IUser;

class User implements UserAlias {
    name:string;
}
```

But it throws error when compiling:

```
E:\WORKSPACE\app\typescripts>tsc main.ts
E:/WORKSPACE/app/typescripts/main.ts(3,27): The property 'IUser'
    does not exist on value of type 'commons'
E:/WORKSPACE/app/typescripts/main.ts(3,19): A module cannot be aliased
    to a non-module type
```

How to fix it?

Comment: How are you loading your modules? Bundling, AMD or commonjs?

Comment: commonjs, the default of typescript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To create an alias for an interface, you can extend it on a local interface:

I have tested this with:

*commons.ts*

```
export interface IUser {
    name: string;
}
```

*app.ts*

```
import commons = module("commons");

interface userAlias extends commons.IUser {
}

class User implements userAlias {
    name: string;
}
```

I have changed the commons.ts slightly because when you use External Modules don't usually have a `module` declaration inside of them - the file is the module. The `module` declaration is used for internal modules.

You can read more about that in section 9.4 of the [TypeScript language specification](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf).

Comment: and you may want to disable the [tslint no-empty-interface-check](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-empty-interface/) with `// tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty-interface`

Answer (score 2):

You can always alias on importing:

```js
import { IUser as userAlias } from "commons"
```

Ancient question, I know, but for anyone landing here now...

Answer (score 1):

## Type

As alternative for [fiddur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71602896/860099) answer, you can use `type` after import

```
import { IUser } from 'commonsl';

type userAlias = IUser ;
```